# How to use Jquery inside reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need question about using jquery inside of reactjs.
I just need to write dropdown sidebar menu using jquery.
But  i do not know how to use jquery inside of react function.
Please help me.

In my Case:

```
  <nav class="sidebar">
      <div class="text">Side Menu</div>
     <ul>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="feat-btn">
            Features
            <span class="fas fa-caret-down first"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="feat-show">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Pages</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Elements</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="serv-btn">
            Services
            <span class="fas fa-caret-down second"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="serv-show">
            <li>
              <a href="#">App Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Web Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Feedback</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

The jquery Code is here:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("click");
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass("show");
    });
      $('.feat-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .feat-show').toggleClass("show");
        $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.serv-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .serv-show').toggleClass("show1");
        $('nav ul .second').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('nav ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
      });
```

I searched in google but did not find it.

PLEASE I NEED HELP!

Comment: https://medium.com/how-to-react/how-to-use-jquery-in-your-react-app-b425727a32fd

Comment: Why even use React then?